# Grails 2.3 - ClassNotFoundException in jobs

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using Grails `2.1.4` till now, and I have some groovy files in `grails-app/job/` folder, for example `RefreshCustomerMatrixJob.groovy`.

I migrated to Grails `2.3.M1`, and start getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

To fix that I needed to move the file to `src/groovy` folder.

What's the differerence between Grails versions that made me needed to move this files?

Comment: It looks like the code under `grails-app/job` is not getting put into the classpath.
Have you tried reinstalling the plugin?